# Does Melty Blood Actress Again Current Code add to Melty Blood ReACT?

Tags: melty-blood

When I was playing Melty Blood, I learned of Melty Blood ReACT and how it had the original story plus an additional set of stories done though the arcade mode which focuses on White Len's manipulation of TATARI. I stopped playing the original Melty Blood and of course I had to restart my route progression.

Now I've come to know about the upcoming Steam Release of [Melty Blood Actress Again Current Code](http://store.steampowered.com/app/411370/). From what I have read, its story is a squeal to Melty Blood

> as Dust of Osiris is a future Sion in control of TATARI that comes about after the original TATARI was destroyed.

Also, in the [Type-Moon Wiki](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Melty_Blood_Actress_Again) it says

> Melty Blood Actress Again is the first game of the Melty Blood series which can be considered a sequel rather than an expansion or port of a previous game.

However, according to [VNDB](http://vndb.org/v165), it's just another release like Melty Blood ReACT. So I am wondering, does Melty Blood Actress Again Current Code contain the story lines from Melty Blood ReACT and just add this sequel storyline on top (along with new game mechanics) like how ReACT did when it added the Arcade Stories on top of the original Melty Blood, **or** does Actress Again remove any of the stories that was in ReACT?